# Can't link Qt to Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, linker, qt5

I decided to write an application using Qt. I have linked Qt to my Xcode project, but I can't compile example from official site. I am getting this

> error: "ld: framework not found QtUiPlugin clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is for those who are new in xcode & Qt....
Suppose your project name is myproj .

1. write all .CPP,.H & .pro file in a folder.
2. write these commands in terminal------
3. cd /myproj
4. qmake -o makefile myproj.pro
5. qmake -spec macx-g++
6. qmake &&make.

after successfull build ...

7. qmake -spec macx-xcode

then your project folder will be having xcode file open it by double clicking...... now you can edit your application in XCODE.

In addition, Please follow this article it will help you to Link Qt to Xcode

[Qt Setup With Xcode](http://www.hankai.org/blog/2015/01/23/qt-setup-with-xcode/)

Comment: Thanks, Assam! You helped me a lot!

Comment: @Murad You are welcome, If you have more questions in QT or Xcode, I'm willing to help.